# Mountain Lion OSX Server One IP Virtual Sites www resolving to wrong Site

Tags: macos, network, osx-server, dns

I am trying to get 2 domains working properly with one static IP on ML OSX Server.

When I set a domain = www.domain2.com- it resolves to domain1.com. 
I have dns set for domain 2 at godaddy, where www.domain2.com and domain2.com both resolve to the IP.

I set an additional domain for domain2 in the server control panel as www.domain2.com. Both sites listen on the same IP.

Domain1 has a nameserver setup for the domain on a co-located mac mini.

============================================================================

I have two sites and one ip .I would like for the www subdomain to work for www.mysecondsite.com. after adding the subdomain www.mysecondsite.com in the control panel for osx server-- when I type www.mysecondsite.com the browser loads  www.firstsite.com.

I do not have enough points to post in the comments. All I did was setup the server. left the default site as is . added firstsite. added secondsite. added www.secondsite.com in the subdomain portion of secondsite's preference box.

This is a new install. am i missing something?

Comment: I advise you to explain more clearly what you went to obtain in your 1st sentence with clear different names.
For example, bob and alice are much clearer than domain1 and domain2. Real names will be OK too as long as they aren't the origin of the problem.

Comment: @ubiquitousDave If you can add additional information, it may help. For example: providing screenshots of your server's setup from the Server.app -> Websites section would be beneficial.

Answer (score 1):

here is what I did that messed things up.

I set domain1 as the hostname, when I should have been using an alias like server.domain1.com. Also, i had the static ip selected in both domains. So, I changed the hostname to server.domain1 and then changed both domains to listen on any port.